# With vim mode turned on, why does gU make the current word uppercase instead of waiting for a movement?

Tags: fish

I have:

```
$one two three
     ^
```

I press `gU` in normal case

Expected behavior:

Nothing happens until I enter a movement

Actual behavior:

```
$one TWO three
        ^
```

Why is the actual behavior different from what I expected?

More detailed questions:

- Is this a bug or intended?
- Is this something I can change with config?

Comment: `:verbose nmap gU`

Comment: AFAIU the Q is not about `vim` bit about vim-like mode of `fish` shell which is free to be implemented as close or as remote to `vim` as the `fish` authors decide.

Comment: You might get a better answer on the fish mailing list: https://sourceforge.net/projects/fish/lists/fish-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it was [initially implemented back in 2014](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/commit/b0e94c15e), and it doesn't look like anyone's noticed that it's not the same as Vim. The Vi keybindings are relatively neglected, as I often point out, because none of the committers use them with any regularity and they are relatively rarely the subject of community contributions.

I've [filed an issue to track](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/7486) but it will probably need a volunteer to take a crack at it.